# Finding $\overrightarrow v(t)$ and $\overrightarrow r(t)$ when given $\overrightarrow a(t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Suppose an object moves so that its acceleration is given by $\overrightarrow a(t) = \langle 0, -4 \cos(t), -3 \sin(t) \rangle$  with $\overrightarrow v(0)= \langle 0,0,3 \rangle$ and $\overrightarrow r(0) = \langle 0,4,0 \rangle$.  Find $\overrightarrow v(t)$ and $\overrightarrow r(t)$  for the object.

So $\overrightarrow v(t) = \int \overrightarrow a(t)dt = (-4 \sin(t))j + (3 \cos(t))k + \vec{C_1}$

And $\overrightarrow r(t) = \int \overrightarrow v(t)dt = (4 \cos(t))j + (3\sin(t))k + \vec{C_2}$

I'm not sure what to do from here, though.

Comment: Use the only piece of information you didnt use yet; substitute $t=0$ in your expressions.

Comment: use $C_1$ and $C_2$ and avoid using $C$ for both

Comment: @CalvinKhor so for $\overrightarrow v(0) = \langle 0,0,3 \rangle$ would I use it like so: $-4sin(0) + 3cos(3) + C = \overrightarrow v(0)$

Comment: @mvw, yes I can see they are two different $C$'s now.  I'm still confused about what I'm supposed to be doing with this problem.  From my optic, it looks like I found $\overrightarrow r(t)$ and $\overrightarrow v(t)$ but all the examples I find continue past the point where I currently am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow v(t) = \int \overrightarrow a(t)dt = \langle 0,-4 \sin(t),3 \cos(t)\rangle + \overrightarrow C_1$$

$$\overrightarrow r(t) = \int \overrightarrow v(t)dt = \langle 0 , 4 \cos(t),3\sin(t) \rangle + \overrightarrow C_1t+\overrightarrow C_2$$

---

$$\overrightarrow v(0)= \langle 0,0,3 \rangle$$
$$\overrightarrow v(0)=\langle 0,0,3 \rangle= \langle 0,-4\sin(0),3 \cos(0)\rangle +\overrightarrow C_1 $$
$$\overrightarrow C_1=\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$$

---

$$\overrightarrow r(0) = \langle 0,4,0 \rangle$$
$$\overrightarrow r(0) = \langle 0,4,0 \rangle= \langle 0,4 \cos(0),3 \sin(0) \rangle+\overrightarrow C_1\times 0+\overrightarrow C_2$$
$$\overrightarrow C_2=\langle 0,0,0 \rangle$$

Comment: What is the $t$ after your $C_1$?

Comment: integration of a constant number $k$ is $kx+k'$

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see.  You integrated it when you found $r(t)$

Comment: How did you get $\overrightarrow C_2 = 0$?  I see how you got that for $\overrightarrow C_1$

Comment: please see my update

Comment: I'll have to think about the way you got that a little more.  $C_1$ is crystal clear but if $C_2$ is an unknown how can you can conclude that it is $0$ just by adding a zero vector to it?

Comment: I fixed a mistake. see it as an equation. both sides must be equal.

Comment: I completely understand this now.  Thanks!